What determines FILE Permissions: Oracle or UNIX?
Oracle 10g
Consider an Oracle Directory 'FOOBIZ'.
Record for FOOBIZ In ALL_TAB_PRIVS is as follows:
Grantor Grantee Schema Table_Name  Privlege Type 
USER   ADMIN   SYS    FOOBIZ      EXECUTE  Directory
USER   ADMIN   SYS    FOOBIZ      READ     Directory
USER   ADMIN   SYS    FOOBIZ      WRITE    Directory

Oracle process uses UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE and writes 'foobar_output.txt' to RHEL Box.
RHEL File Permissions for foobar_output.txt
owner(oracle-read,write)
group(dba-read)
others(no access)

Question:
Does Oracle Permissions as defined in ALL_TAB_PRIVS determine Unix Level permissions when using UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE to write 'foobar_output.txt' or does RHEL setting determine file permissions?
Even though I can write the file via PL/SQL using UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE, I'm unable to access it  after I write it.

Both are long retired: RHEL6 in 2020 and Oracle 10G in 2012 (!). Let me remember you that we are now living in 2024.
